# How can I check a checkbox in Access as I move from record to record?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access database which has a checkbox that I need to see if it's "false" or "true" as I go from record to record.  If the checkbox is true the label font color and name should change.

This is my code but it's not working properly:

```
Private Sub Check796_Click()
  lngRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    lngBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    If Me.Check796 = vbTrue Then
       Me.Label797.Caption = "Hold"
       Me.Label797.ForeColor = lngRed
    Else
       Me.Label797.Caption = "UnHold"
       Me.Label797.ForeColor = lngBlack
    End If    
End Sub
```

If it's checked it should be red and say "Hold" but, if it's unchecked it should say "UnHold".  If I check the "Hold" checkbox it's works but, when I go to the next record which is unchecked it says "Hold" as well.  When I close the application and go back into the record with the checkbox clicked the label says "UnHold" when it should say "Hold".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute the code again on `Form_Current`:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Current()
  lngRed = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    lngBlack = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    If Me.Check796 = vbTrue Then
       Me.Label797.Caption = "Hold"
       Me.Label797.ForeColor = lngRed
    Else
       Me.Label797.Caption = "UnHold"
       Me.Label797.ForeColor = lngBlack
    End If    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it without any VBA:

- Add your checkbox with the Control Source set to your boolean
  (Yes/No) field.
- Add a **textbox** (format to look like a label).
  Give it a Control
  Source of `=Choose(Abs([Check796])+1,'UnHold','Hold')`
  A boolean
  returns -1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.
  `ABS` removes the sign, so
  it's now 0 and 1.
  Add 1 as `CHOOSE` needs to start at 1.
- Select the text and in the **FORMAT** ribbon in **Form Design Tools** 
  select `Conditional Formatting`.
  Select `Field Value Is` `equal to`
  `"Hold"` and format as red font.